# How do I clean this dataframe?

Tags: pandas

In row 2, I have a value "AVE" in the 'address' column that I would like to join with the 'address' value in row 1.  The result should be row 1 'address' reads as "NEWPORT AVE / HIGHLAND AVE".  How do I do this?

I also need to perform the same function with row 3 where 'action_taken' reads as "SERVICE RENDERED" with "RENDERED" taken from row 4.

```
  |incident_no | date_reported | time_reported | address                | incident_type | action_taken
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 2100030948 | 2021-05-16    | 23:21:00      | NEWPORT AVE / HIGHLAND | ERRATIC M/V   | UNFOUNDED
2 | <NA>       | NaT           | NaT           | AVE                    | NaN           | NaN
3 | 2100030947 | 2021-05-16    | 23:16:00      | FALMOUTH ST            | SECURITY CHECK| SERVICE
4 | <NA>       | NaT           | NaT           | NaN                    | NaN           | RENDERED
5 | 2100030946 | 2021-05-16    | 22:55:00      | PINE RD                | SECURITY CHECK| SERVICE
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First columns from list forward filling missing values, then group by them and aggregate join with remove missing values:

```
cols = ['incident_no','date_reported','time_reported']

df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()

df = df.groupby(cols).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())).reset_index()
```